# pyaudio freezing program in multiprocess with wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, pyaudio

Calling p = pyaudio.PyAudio() in my app causes it to freeze when it's called inside of a multiprocess. Note I'm running the app with pythonw instead of python. When I remove the wx modules, it works fine. Any suggestions on how to fix? I'm using python 3.5 on MacOS

```
from app import frame, app
import pyaudio
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker():
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    while True:
        print('starting worker')
        print('pyaudio', p)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = mp.Process(target=worker)
    p1.start()

    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

    p1.join()
```

app.py

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, title='Hello World')


frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you import your `app` module it is executing all the code and blocking at `app.MainLoop()` while it is processing and dispatching events. Control does not return to your main module until `MainLoop` returns.